# How to dynamically add headers from map when defining a RouteBuilder

Tags: java, apache-camel, fluent

I'm creating a `RouteBuilder` for a test:

```java
final RouteBuilder routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(start).routeId(id).
                process(myProcessor).
                to(end);
    }
};
camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
```

and I need to also set some headers coming from a `Map<String, String>`. In other words I'd like to do something like:

```java
headers.entrySet().
        forEach(header -> {
            setHeader(header.getKey(), constant(header.getValue()));
        });
```

but that `setHeader` should be related to the `RouteDefinition` that I was creating inside the `#configure` method of the `RouteBuilder`.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the DSL should have N .setHeader(.., ..)?

Answer (score 0):

Typing from my mobile. Thus format may not be correct:

```
final RouteBuilder routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder() { 
     @Override
     public void configure() throws Exception {
        RouteDefinition route = from(start).routeId(id);
        headers.entrySet().
            forEach(header -> {
                route = route.setHeader(header.getKey(), 
                    constant(header.getValue()));
            });
            route.process(myProcessor).
            to(end);
        }
};
camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder);`
```